Юнити клавиши плохо прожимаются
 void Update()
 {
     H = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
     V = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
 }
 private void FixedUpdate()
 {
     if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0  && iscollision)
     {
         rb.velocity = new Vector2(H, 0).normalized * Speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
     }
     if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") != 0  && iscollision)
     {
         rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, V).normalized * Speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
     }
 }
 private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
 {
     iscollision = true;
 }
 private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
 {
     iscollision = false;
 }

Управление очень корявое, клавиши прожимаются не всегда и не сразу, иногда игрок начинает тормозить хотя такого быть не должно. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, что не так и как чинить.
